# how to run umbraco in vs 2005?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, umbraco

i am new in umbraco.How can we attach a user control file(.ascx) from visual studio 2005 to umbraco?is any body knows please reply

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy your assembly (dll) into the `/bin` folder of your umbraco installation. There should also be a /usercontrols folder for this purpose as well... If it's a user control you will also need to copy the .ascx file as well.

[Using .NET User Controls](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/introduction-to-umbraco/developer-introduction/using-net-user-controls)

Comment: hi Mitch Wheat,thank you for your reply.but i cant open a web application using vs2005.

Comment: hi Mitch,it will not work in visual studio 2005.vs2008 and later editions only support